# Vue v-show not working with v-for to hide v-list menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-rendering

I am trying to hide an admin menu using `v-show`. In the code below the `isAdmin` value is false, yet the menu still shows. I have also tried `v-if` but that doesn't work either.

```
        <v-list v-show="isAdmin">
          <v-list-item v-for="item in adminItems" :key="item.title" @click="handleNavigtion(item)" router>
            <v-list-item-action class="pr-1 pl-2 mr-1">
              <v-icon :class="activeMenuItem.includes(item.title) ? 'blue--text' : ''" :title="item.title">
                {{ item.icon }}
              </v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content :class="activeMenuItem.includes(item.title) ? 'blue--text' : ''">
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
```

I also tried with the `v-show/if` inside the `v-list-item` element.

```
 <v-list-item v-if="isAdmin" v-for="item in adminItems">...</v-list-item>
```

Additionally, the component uses Typescript's `get` for making `isAdmin` a computed property. When I try to access this in the template using
`{{ isAdmin }}` the value displays either `true` or `false` correctly.

```
 get isAdmin() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('isAdmin')
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `v-if` and `v-for` cannot coexist, and it is a bad idea to use nested too. However, when you are seeing `adminItems` the `isAdmin` must be true, isn't it? try this `v-show="!isAdmin"`

Comment: It is a better idea to use `computed` props to filter the list, then without any condition render it. Consider that `v-show` render element but just hide them. `v-if` makes more sense to be used.

Comment: Thanks for response. The adminItems show even if isAdmin is false. I thought I saw v-if or v-show working with v-for before, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: I am using Typescript `get` functionality to return a computed property. I have edited my question to add more code.

Comment: Hmm. Please wrap it in `div` or `template` and use `v-if` and give it a re-run. https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/156. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element. Best to put the `v-if` or `v-show` on a parent element.

**Working Demo :**

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    adminItems: [{
        title: 'abc',
      icon: 'Icon 1'
    }, {
        title: 'def',
      icon: 'Icon 2'
    }],
    activeMenuItem: ['abc', 'def']
  },
  computed: {
    isAdmin() { 
      return true; // Replace `true` with `false` to see the changes.
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.14.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-list v-show="isAdmin">
    <v-list-item v-for="item in adminItems" :key="item.title" @click="handleNavigtion(item)" router>
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title><br>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not possible to use v-for together with v-if or v-show.
But I tried something and it worked.

```
  <v-list dense nav v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
  <v-list-item
    dense
    :to="item.url"
    :exact="true"
    v-if="mixPermissao($options.name, item.name)"
  >
    <v-list-item-icon>
      <v-icon :color="item.color">{{ item.icon }} </v-icon>
    </v-list-item-icon>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

I put the v-for in the v-list and the v-if in the v-list-item and it worked.